# Why OpenCV dosen't overload operator */+ for class cv::Mat

Tags: opencv

In the definition of the class `cv::Mat` of OpenCV, I've found the definitions of operator `()` and `=`. I think it's good if OpenCV overloaded operator `+-*/` etc. for matrix just like MATLAB. Why OpenCV does not overload operator `+-*/` for matrix? Are these on the schedule? Or, is that not a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix operations are defined in `cxmat.hpp`. I don't know what advantage it has, to do it this way, but I guess they have their reasons.

Comment: Thanks. I've found `cxmat.hpp` in OpenCV 2.1 and it have definitions for operator `*-/+`. But I also found there is not cxmat.hpp from 2.2 any more instead of `mat.hpp` where have those definitions.

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Comment: @Antonio How is the answer outdated? Are they no longer defined in the mentioned header? Are they now in a different header? Are they now in the core header? Or did OpenCV scrap support entirely? That said: for me I can compile code that relies on the `+` and `-` operators for `cv::Mat` , but my code inspection fails to tell me where they are located.

Comment: I just did the digging (am even after 5 minutes not allowed to edit a comment; WTF stackoverflow?); the definitions for the headers are now located in `mat.hpp`.

Also, why does StackOverflow keep becoming more and more annoying? I am seriously starting to think that it is a good idea to not even consider contributing to it. It is so freaking annoying.

Comment: @Joeppie Rustig maar! If you are unhappy with a comment older than 5 minutes, copy it to your clipboard, delete it, and resubmit it updated. If you have serious problem with some feature, you can go to [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and see why certain decision have been made, and even propose changes (but you must have a very solid basis)
You should learn sooner than later that Stackoverflow is an invaluable resource for Software Engineers, and contributing to it is also a learning experience, as you'll see other experienced users spotting all inaccuracies and allow you to be better

Comment: @Antonio Please go and patronize someone else, I am not interested, not then, not now, and not ever again. As a 10+ years software engineer, several of which I have used SO, I am now at the point where I would recommend people to not use SO, since it is becoming a less and less good place to ask questions. More and more it just a convenient lookup tool. And what I pointed out is just one of many other symptoms of that.

Comment: @Joeppie You should give more rationale behind your frustration than just "after 5 minutes I cannot edit my comments". Again, Meta is the place where to discuss this. On a personal note, I have learnt so much by asking (and answering) questions in SO.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry but...

Yes, OpenCV overloads all these operators. Try them out!

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat m1 = Mat::zeros(2, 2, CV_32FC1);
    Mat m2 = Mat::ones(2, 2, CV_32FC1);
    m1.at<float>(0, 0) = 2.0f;

    cout << (m2*2) << endl;
    cout << m1*m2 << endl;
    cout << m1+m2 << endl;
    cout << m1-m2 << endl;
}
```